# checking if data existing in my array of dict

Tags: python, django

i'd like to check if data exists in all my fields and if there is None in one field return False for all the rest otherwise return True if all the fields are filled up. It's only returning True. Can Anyone help

```
ret = {'complete': False}

try:
    company_director = CompanyDirector.objects.filter(company__token=token).values(
        'username','directorTitle','directorInitials',
        'directorName','administrativeOrder',
        'directorSurname','directorId','directorQualification',
        'releventExperiance','education','directorInsolvent',
        'directorProffesionalAssociation','profileImage','profileImageThumbNail',
        'directorProffesionalAssociationList','releventExperiance','shareInBusiness',
        'profileImage','qualifications','criminalOffence','capInBuss','spSkill').first()
    if company_director:
        ret['complete'] = True
        for field, value in company_director.items():
            if (type(value) in [str, unicode] is None and len(value)) == "":
                ret['complete'] = False
                break;
            if str(exclude_items) in field:
                if (type(value) in [str, unicode] and len(value) > 0 and value is not None) or type(value) in \
                        [int]:
                    ret['complete'] = True
except ValueError as e:
    print (e)
return Response(ret)
```

Comment: What are you trying to check here: `if (type(value) in [str, unicode] is None and len(value)) == "":`?

Comment: check if the value of the item is None or the len is empty

Comment: Have you tried: if not all(variable) ?

Comment: @AmaraGbaguidi If you want to know if `value` is `None` or empty, consider `if not value:`. That thing you have written does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
def valid(var):
    if var in [None, '']:
        return False
    return True

ret = {'complete': False}
if company_director:
    ret['complete'] = all(map(valid, company_director.values()))
```

`valid(value)` returns `True` if its valid and `False` if not valid (not valid = None or ''). `map(valid, company_director.values())` calls valid for every attribute and returns a `list`-like object with the booleans. `all(...)` returns `True` if and only if all the booleans of the iterable are `True`. So basically ret['complete'] is `True` if and only if all the attributes of `company_director` are valid. The default value is set to `False` because if `if company_director:` fails you do not have a `company_director` and thus it is not complete.

Answer (score -1):

```
ret = {'complete': True}
if company_director:
    for field, value in company_director.items():
        if value in [None, ""]:
            ret['complete'] = False
            break
```

Comment: Hi @RajKris , still returning False

Comment: I suggested some changes that handle some new cases but if it is returning true you should tell us what does `print company_director` prints to the console.

Comment: Cmpany_director prints out this [<CompanyDirector: YANNICKe>]

Comment: This answer would be better if you included some explanation about _why_ it is the solution, to help OP and others learn.

Comment: I built an API, in python /Django,  from the frontend side, im checking whether  a field is None or empty then return False for the entire form , or return True ,if all the fields are filled up. That's what i'm trying to achieve so far

Comment: I initialized the flag as True,  and if any of the fields of the object is None or empty the flag gets updated as False, this is what is happening in the above code. @AmaraGbaguidi If still returning False, please confirm if the object is having a None or empty field. Evidently from the above code we can infer that if value is None or Empty, it gets set to False otherwise it should return  True

Comment: I have done some test cases. And tweaked some stuffs, but your code was the reference.It worked.....!!!!

Comment: Please accept this answer or upvote it if this answer helped.